# Clap switch circuit too sensitive

Tags: switches, microphone

I followed the clap switch circuit in [this youtube video.](https://youtu.be/uQ1LPFqSyqE?t=48)

[image: Clapper Schematic]

The circuit is always ON.  I replaced the condenser microphone with a photoresistor and the circuit is still ON.

Which part is making the microphone too sensitive?

Comment: Do you want to use it as a clap switch, or are you trying to convert it to use a photoresistor?  In either case, edit your question and put in a diagram of the circuit you built.

Comment: Asking respondents to youtube videos (or read papers/articles or visit external links) is not a preferred way of asking questions. The post should be made self-contained as much as possible.

Comment: Disconnect 47 uF. Increase 1M (preferred) OR decrease 120k until LED JUST goes off. || 10k value depends on LDR resistance with light - V at 10K/LDR junction should be in 4 to 8V range when Vbat is 9V. | Now replace 47 uF. Circuit will then perhaps respond to sudden light increase. BUT what are you trying to achieve - please describe IN DETAIL

Comment: IMPORTANT:  What do you want the photoswitch to do? - Respond to a sudden increase OR decrease in light, or come on when light is present or ... ? | This may not be the best circuit.

Answer (score 1):

The microphone picks up sounds that produces AC that is coupled through the capacitor and activates the transistors and LED.

Without sounds and without the capacitor then the LED should be turned off.

If the LDR is connected from the base of transistor #1 to ground then light on the LDR will cause the LED to light.

If transistor #1 is removed and the LDR is connected from the base of transistor #2 to ground then the LED will turn on if the LDR has no light and light on the LDR will turn off the LED.

If C and E on the first transistor are swapped then the reverse happens.
[image: clap switch]